# ¿Es una buena práctica de programación en JAVA (POO) inicializar un objeto hasta que sea usado?

Tags: java, poo

¿Es una buena práctica de programación en JAVA (POO)  inicializar un objeto hasta que sea usado? o es mejor inicializarlo de una vez en el método constructor para evitarme problemas posteriores?

Por ejemplo:

Yo tengo la clase Main principal y aquí inicializo mi objeto reloj desde el contructor de una vez:

```
  public class AplicacionPrincipal(){

     private Reloj reloj;

     public ApplicacionPrincipal{

        reloj = new Reloj();
     }

     public void iniciarCronometro(){

        reloj.iniciarReloj();
     }
  }
```

Ó SERÍA MEJOR INICIALIZARLO HASTA QUE YO PONGA EN MARCHA EL RELOJ PARA NO GASTAR MEMORIA AHORITA MIENTRAS NO USO EL RELOJ (Supomiendo que tengo muchas instancias de ese reloj y quiero que mientras se vayan utilizando se vayan inicializando para no gastar tanta memoria de un jalón y no los inicialice en el contructor sino hasta que lo utilice, algo como esto:

```
  public class AplicacionPrincipal(){

     private Reloj reloj;

     public ApplicacionPrincipal{
        // Constructor vacio por ahora
     }

     public void iniciarCronometro(){

        reloj = new Reloj(); // Hasta aquí inicializo mi objeto cronometro
        reloj.iniciarReloj();
     }
  }
```

No se si tenga sentido cuidar la memoria tanto, o dejar que se cargue de una vez en el constructorel objeto reloj para mejorar el performance a costa de iniciar con un programa que ocupe más memoria.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta puede tener varias respuestas.. creo que una de las consideraciones que se deben de hacer es en donde vas a utilizar el objeto, si el objeto es utilizado en varios de los métodos conservando su estado la declaración debe ser en el constructor, por otro lado si el objeto se va a usar solo en un método y su estado solo tiene ese alcance pues solo se construye en el ambito que lo requieres.

Comment: Me parece bien tu respuesta, aunque no se si viste mi segundo ejemplo, ahí no lo estoy declarando y a la vez inicializando como me acabas de comentar, sino que lo declaro como propiedad de la misma clase y lo inicializo hasta usar el reloj en el metodo iniciarCronometro(), la pregunta es: ¿Lo vez eso como mala práctica? Mi justificación es: "Para que lo inicializo el reloj desde el contructor, si aún no voy a iniciar todavia el reloj enseguida", sino hasta que le de a un boton llamado playButton

Comment: Yo diria... ¿porqué la clase tiene un objeto Reloj como atributo si solo se requiere usarlo en un método y para una actividad especifica??? Si pasamos a UML los atríbutos de una clase tienen dos connotaciones: o son de composición o son de agregación. En su ejemplo, El Reloj es escencial para la clase, es por ejemplo la llanta del carro o solo es el aromatizador?

Comment: ¿Por qué? Por que si lo voy a ocupar en otros metodos como pausarReloj() y detenerReloj(), que no los pongo en el codigo de ejemplo por que sólo quería ilustrar el hecho de inicializar un objeto no de una vez desde el constructor como por lo regular se hace, sino inicializando ese objeto reloj hasta que yo de en click un boton que invoca al metodo iniciarCronometro(), como lo pongo en el segundo ejemplo. El tema de alcances lo tengo muy claro, mi interrogante es si es mala práctica inicializar no en el constructor, sino en otro metodo más adelante como lo hago en mi segundo ejemplo.

Comment: ok, en ese caso es preferible inicializarlo en el constructor, de lo contrario cada vez que un método desee hacer uso de el debería validar si esta inicializado para no generar un NullPointerException.

Comment: ¡Exacto!, con el fin de ayudarle al Garbage Collect, lo que hago es inicializar el objeto hasta que la uso como en el segundo ejemplo y cuando le doy en detenerReloj(), hago que el objeto reloj se haga nulo  )y enseguida mando a llamar de forma manual al Garbaje Collect por medio de System.gc(),  Para esto hace un if la comparación si el objeto ya esta creado con un "== null", pero creo que al final mi codigo lo estoy haciendo un poco confuso. Por eso mis dudas.

Comment: Todo por mi afan de tratar de liberar memoria inmediatamente que no uso un objeto, y no hasta que el Garbage Collector lo considera así por medio de sus algoritmos internos. Al hacer pruebas en el monitor de tareas, si logro mi cometido e inmediatamente destruyo el reloj con un = null, e invocar al garbaje collector manualmente, libero inmediatamente el uso de memoria de mi aplicación, pero creo que eso al final no me sirve de mucho al mantener mi codigo.

Comment: Buenas, si tu intención es la de optimizar recursos y/o tiempos de ejecución. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear tu objeto una sola vez , y utilizarlo cambiando sus parametros para obtener distintos resultados. ¿Tu tiras y compras un reloj nuevo, cada vez que miras la hora? Eso es muy costoso. Igual que si andas creando y destruyendo objetos por que si.

Comment: Me parece difícil responder a tu pregunta sin conocer con claridad el **contexto**. Puede que en un escenario convenga una cosa u otra. El ejemplo de las llantas del coche me parece importante para entender lo que es esencial en una clase y lo que no lo es. Si `Reloj` es esencial para que tu clase *ande*, entonces no hay por qué dudar en inicializarlo en el constructor. Si no lo es, ten en cuenta que las clases admiten también múltiples constructores y que, en algunos casos el objeto también puede ser inicializado desde un método de la propia clase. Sea como sea, lo importante es el contexto.

Comment: Gracias a todos sus respuestas me resultaron muy valiosas y de utilidad. Saludos colegas programadores.

Comment: @MissionaryrobotRobot, Esperamos que las dudas se vayan aclarando, en temas como estos es muy posible que no hayan respuestas definitivas, pero vamos construyendo conocimiento. Como dato, cuando usas el System.gc(), no ejecutas el Garbage Collector, solo le estas solicitando a la VM que se ejecute, la VM administra la petición y decidira cuando ejecutarlo.

Comment: Para un hilo no hay mucha diferencia, @MissionaryrobotRobot tal vez quieras contarnos cuanta carga concurrente esperas y que tipo de optimización estás buscando.